# sqlalchemy bulk_save_objects error on one row

Tags: python, error-handling, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert, bulk-load

If I use bulk_save_objects for a large set of data, and it errors out for one row. The data base I' using is mysql. Typically it doesn't insert anything.

What if I want it to continue to run after it errors out one row and insert all the other rows?

```
try:
    session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    session.commit()
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

Comment: So because a `session` manages a `transaction` and transactions must be `atomic`, if one row fails, they all must fail.

Comment: Depending on what the actual error is, you'll want to use your database's idea of "insert or ignore" or some such, but you've failed to mention which database you are using (and what error you're getting).

Comment: The data base I'm using is mysql. Yes. I looked into insert ignore and it's a useful solution if there's duplicate key. But I'm just thinking of the use case that if there's an error due to anything. For example, there's one data doesn't fit the data type. Is this something the engineer has to build?

Comment: You could use savepoints, or "subtransactions", in some cases, but that means you cannot bulk insert, but must try to insert each row separately.